# Параллельная прокрутка скроллов

Tags: delphi, прокрутка

Есть несколько компонентов Memo, как задать парную прокрутку скроллбара,  т.е. если я прокручиваю в одном мемо, параллельно должно опускаться и в остальных.

Comment: вы каким-либо образом пытались решить задачу? Есть ведь, наверное, у компонента событие, возникающее при скролле? К нескольким компонентам ведь можно  назначит один и тот же обработчик события? Несколько элементов можно сложить в список? Событие получает параметр  `sender` идентифицирующее объект у которого оно вызвано, чтобы сравнить его со списком? Можно ли узнать текущую позицию скролла,и изменить его программно?

Answer (score 0):

На форме всего 2 Мемо, у обоих ScrollBars установлен как ssVertical

```
implementation
{$R *.DFM}
...
private
    { Private declarations }
    lbproc1, lbproc2: TWndMethod;
    procedure NewProc1(var msg: TMessage);
    procedure NewProc2(var msg: TMessage);
...
implementation

{$R *.DFM}
procedure TForm1.NewProc1;
begin
  case msg.Msg of
    WM_VSCROLL, LB_SETCURSEL,
    WM_KEYFIRST..WM_KEYLAST,
    WM_MOUSEFIRST..WM_MOUSELAST:
      lbproc2(msg);
  end;
  lbproc1(msg);
end;
procedure TForm1.NewProc2;
begin
  case msg.Msg of
    WM_VSCROLL, LB_SETCURSEL,
    WM_KEYFIRST..WM_KEYLAST,
    WM_MOUSEFIRST..WM_MOUSELAST:
      lbproc1(msg);
  end;
  lbproc2(msg);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lbproc1 := Memo1.WindowProc;
  Memo1.WindowProc := NewProc1;
  lbproc2 := Memo2.WindowProc;
  Memo2.WindowProc := NewProc2;
end;
```

Вот и всё